# Mifare desfire apdu command

Tags: smartcard, apdu, mifare

I have a smart card that contains a Mifare Desfire EV1 contactless chip, and I am trying to send an authentication request with masterkey to the contactless part (Mifare Desfire), so I am sending this command :

```
 -- Auth Req with Master key
         >>> cmd  = 90 AA 00 00 01 00 00
         <<< data =
         <<< sw   = 68 84
```

I don't know why I am getting this error code, it seems that the command was send to contat ship ?

Can you help me please to figure out what's the problem ? is there any step before to "activate" to contactless part ?

BtW : I tried with those readers : Omnikey5321v2 and ACR122U-A9

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the response status you are getting (`SW = 0x68 84`) actually means. However, it seems that you are missing the `LE` byte in your command.

> Wrapping of native MIFARE DESFire EV1 APDUs:
>
> ```
> CLA    | INS     | P1    | P2    | LC        | Data        | LE
> 0x90     MIFARE    0x00    0x00    Length of   MIFARE        0x00
>          DESFire                   wrapped     DESFire EV1
>          EV1 CMD                   data        command
>          Code                                  parameter(s)
> ```

Like `P1` & `P2`, the `LE` byte should be always present and set to `0x00`, and any other values are not allowed.

So your authentication command should actually be:

```
cmd  = 90 AA 00 00 01 00 00 00
```